# How can I restore SSL to a site where it has stopped working?

Tags: ssl, iis

I have several sites running on a VPS on IIS and through Cloudflare (free account).  One of these sites has recently stopped working on SSL.  The error on my server end is a 403 Forbidden

The original settings on Cloudflare were

- Strict SSL
- SSL/TLS Reminder is On
- DNS A Record for the domain name is proxied
- Under Page Rules: Always Use HTTPS HTTP/2 is OFF HTTP/3 (with QUIC) is ON
- 0-RTT is ON IPv6 is OFF
- gRPC is OFF
- WebSockets is ON
- Onion Routing is ON
- My plan includes a Cloudflare Universal SSL certificate (expires 6/22).
- In the certificate section Always Use HTTPS is ON

In IIS:

- Original SSL Settings are to Require SSL
- Require Client Certificate

Website

- All links are set to HPPS (CDNs)

All these settings had been working until about 2 weeks ago.  Before this I hadn't touched any of the settings in 2 years

Right now the site is running but only under HTTP not HTTPS.
Cloudflare is set to Flexible and in IIS I turned Require SSL to OFF.

If I go back to the original settings where SSL is required I get a 403 error.

Hoping someone may have some idea on what happened and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: When you flipped Require SSL setting on IIS side, what were the status code/substatus code changes in IIS log files? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code

Comment: You can see clearly that Cloudflare (`108.162.x.x`) tried to connect to your server via HTTP (port 80) and was blocked by "Request SSL" (403.4 is expected). You should let Cloudflare connect via HTTPS (port 443) by switching to Full mode, https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-End-to-end-HTTPS-with-Cloudflare-Part-3-SSL-options (or disable "Require SSL" and stick to Flexible mode). BTW, you shouldn't reveal your server's public IP address in such questions/comments, as that can lead to attacks.

Comment: Thanks - I rewriting my last comment without the IP Address...  2021-08-15 03:03:04 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET / - 80 - 108.162.221.18 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/92.0.4515.131+Safari/537.36 - 403 4 5 119

Comment: Your suggestion to turn off Request SSL and put Cloudflare in Flexible Mode worked.  I still don't understand why this happened or why it won't work as before with Request SSL=true and Cloudflare in Strict mode, but this is working and giving me SSL so that's OK. Thank you very much for your help!